# Repeating a list N times Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, transpose, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I think it's best I provide an example for this one.

```
Input:
    a   2
    b   3
    c   4
    d   1

Output Goal:
    a
    a
    b
    b
    b
    c
    c
    c
    c
    d
```

So I want to repeat the value in Cell A1 n times (n is located in column B1)

I considered using the following function then transposing and stacking the array:

```
=SPLIT(REPT(A1&",",B1),",")
```

However, I was hoping there is a single formula that can solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula:

```
=transpose(split(concatenate(arrayformula(rept(A1:A4&",",B1:B4))),","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",", ARRAYFORMULA(REPT(SPLIT(
 INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(A1:A)), ",")&",", 
 INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))), ","))
```

[image: 0]